# Query Database and remove Charfield Choices based on what is in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have created a booking form using Django forms. For selecting a time I have a series of choices. However, I want to only display those choices in the form if they don't already exist on that data and time.

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core import validators
import datetime

TIME_CHOICES = (
        ('12:00:00', '12pm'),
        ('12:15:00', '12:15pm'),
        ('12:30:00', '12:30pm'),
        ('12:45:00', '12:45pm'),
        ('13:00:00', '1pm'),
        ('13:15:00', '1:15pm'),
        ('13:30:00', '1:30pm'),
        ('13:45:00', '1:45pm'),
        ('14:00:00', '2pm'),
        ('14:15:00', '2:15pm'),
        ('14:30:00', '2:30pm'),
        ('14:45:00', '2:45pm'),
        ('15:00:00', '3pm'),
        ('15:15:00', '3:15pm'),
        ('15:30:00', '3:30pm'),
        ('15:45:00', '3:45pm'),
        ('16:00:00', '4pm'),
        ('16:15:00', '4:15pm'),
        ('16:30:00', '4:30pm'),
        ('16:45:00', '4:45pm'),
        ('17:00:00', '5pm'),
        ('17:15:00', '5:15pm'),
        ('17:30:00', '5:30pm'),
        ('17:45:00', '5:45pm'),
        ('18:00:00', '6pm'),
        ('18:15:00', '6:15pm'),
        ('18:30:00', '6:30pm'),
        ('18:45:00', '6:45pm'),
        ('19:00:00', '7pm'),
        ('19:15:00', '7:15pm'),
        ('19:30:00', '7:30pm'),
        ('19:45:00', '7:45pm'),
        ('20:00:00', '8pm'),
        ('20:15:00', '8:15pm'),
        ('20:30:00', '8:30pm'),
        ('20:45:00', '8:45pm'),
        ('21:00:00', '9pm'),
        ('21:15:00', '9:15pm'),
        ('21:30:00', '9:30pm'),
        ('21:45:00', '9:45pm'),
        ('22:00:00', '10pm'),
        ('22:15:00', '10:15pm'),
        ('22:30:00', '10:30pm'),
        ('22:45:00', '10:45pm'),
    )


class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
        )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False)
    email_address = models.EmailField(default="email@email.com")
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    date_of_booking = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    time_of_booking = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=TIME_CHOICES, default=""
        )
    number_of_people = models.IntegerField()
    special_requests = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):  # code adapted from Models Part 2 FST walkthrough
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + " | " \
             + str(self.date_of_booking) + " at " + str(self.time_of_booking)
```

Here is my views.py fucntion:

```
def make_booking(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print('form saved')
            return redirect(get_bookings)
        else:
            print('broken')
   
    form = BookingForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
        }
    return render(request, 'booking/make_booking.html', context)
```

How do I write a function to remove dates/times already submitted to the database from the dropdown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDXwH.png)

I can only find info that tells me how to record a current session and not how to query the db.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a time choices model instead of having it hardcoded on the models.py. you can then use something like:

```
TimeModel.objects.filter(time=form.time_of_booking).delete()
```